# TASM: error when trying to modify a constant with an instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I get "argument needs type override" error in TASM due to trying to increase a constant value. I also can't use variables, because then I can't simply add them to each other and get the "operand types do not much" error. Is there any way to increase a constant or add two variables? I've tried to use registers - I mean copying the constant to a register and then increase the register and it works, but this does not solve my problem. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
model tiny
.486
.stack 200h

.data
h = 50
w = 100
x = 10
y = 10
k1 = 15
k2 = 0

.code
start:
mov ah, 0      ; graphics mode
mov al, 13h 
int 10h

; main loop
mov cx, 50
pg:
push cx

; top line
mov cx, x+w    ; column
mov dx, y      ; row
mov al, k1     ; white
p1:
mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
jae p1

; bottom line
mov cx, x+w
mov dx, y+h 
mov al, k1    
p2: 
mov ah, 0ch 
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
ja p2

; left line
mov cx, x   
mov dx, y+h
mov al, k1     
p3: 
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p3 

; right line
mov cx, x+w
mov dx, y+h
mov al, k1     
p4:
mov ah, 0ch   
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p4

; delay
mov cx, 01h
mov dx, 4240h
mov ah, 86h
int 15h

; top line
mov cx, x+w 
mov dx, y    
mov al, k2      
p5:
mov ah, 0ch   
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
jae p5

; bottom line
mov cx, x+w 
mov dx, y+h
mov al, k2      
p6: 
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
ja p6

; left line
mov cx, x   
mov dx, y+h 
mov al, k2      
p7: 
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p7 

; right line
mov cx, x+w 
mov dx, y+h  
mov al, k2      
p8:
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p8     

pop cx
dec cx
cmp cx, 50
;inc x
;inc y
jna pg

mov ah,00      ; read keyboard
int 16h         

mov ah,00      ; text mode
mov al,03
int 10h

mov ah,4ch     ; exit
int 21h

end start
```

Comment: Where do you get those errors? Just ran your code and it's good (nice rectangles!).

Comment: Try `h dw 50` instead of `h = 50` in `data`. The same for the others.

Comment: error appear when try increase x and y constants at the end on main loop, also when change them to dw type then get "operand types do not match" and "cant add relative quantities" errors

Comment: When I change only x and y do dw type, there is no errors but instead of rectangle I got white screen.

Comment: constants are copied everywhere they're used, so there isn't a single storage location that can be modified.  That's the whole point of defining constants: it's just another way of writing `add ax, 10` or something, which assembles to an `add ax, imm8`  The constant is embedded right into the instruction.  Anything you want to modify need to be in a register or memory.  Keeping your variables live in registers is good though, if you have enough registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs these changes :

1. Convert your constants into variables
2. Because of the variables, you will need to split the additions.
3. Also, because of the variables, it's necessary to initialize the data segment.

Here is your code with the 3 changes (pointed by "arrows") :

```
.model small
.stack 200h

.data
h dw 50                   ;<=========================
w dw 100                  ;<=========================
x dw 10                   ;<=========================
y dw 10                   ;<=========================
k1 db 15                  ;<=========================
k2 db 0                   ;<=========================

.code
start:
mov ax, @data             ;<=========================
mov ds, ax                ;<=========================

mov ah, 0      ; graphics mode
mov al, 13h 
int 10h

; main loop
mov cx, 50
pg:
push cx

; top line
mov cx, x;+w    ; column  ;<=========================
add cx, w                 ;<=========================
mov dx, y      ; row
mov al, k1     ; white
p1:
mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
jae p1

; bottom line
mov cx, x;+w              ;<=========================
add cx, w                 ;<=========================
mov dx, y;+h              ;<=========================
add dx, h                 ;<=========================
mov al, k1    
p2: 
mov ah, 0ch 
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
ja p2

; left line
mov cx, x   
mov dx, y;+h              ;<=========================
add dx, h                 ;<=========================
mov al, k1     
p3: 
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p3 

; right line
mov cx, x;+w              ;<=========================
add cx, w                 ;<=========================
mov dx, y;+h              ;<=========================
add dx, h                 ;<=========================
mov al, k1     
p4:
mov ah, 0ch   
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p4

; delay
mov cx, 01h
mov dx, 4240h
mov ah, 86h
int 15h

; top line
mov cx, x;+w              ;<=========================
add cx, w                 ;<=========================
mov dx, y    
mov al, k2      
p5:
mov ah, 0ch   
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
jae p5

; bottom line
mov cx, x;+w              ;<========================= 
add cx, w                 ;<=========================
mov dx, y;+h              ;<=========================
add dx, h                 ;<=========================
mov al, k2      
p6: 
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
ja p6

; left line
mov cx, x   
mov dx, y;+h              ;<=========================
add dx, h                 ;<=========================
mov al, k2      
p7: 
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p7 

; right line
mov cx, x;+w              ;<=========================
add cx, w                 ;<=========================
mov dx, y;+h              ;<=========================
add dx, h                 ;<=========================
mov al, k2      
p8:
mov ah, 0ch    
int 10h
dec dx
cmp dx, y
ja p8     

pop cx
dec cx
cmp cx, 50
;inc x
;inc y
jna pg

mov ah,00      ; read keyboard
int 16h         

mov ah,00      ; text mode
mov al,03
int 10h

mov ah,4ch     ; exit
int 21h

end start
```

**Now the filled rectangle** The idea is to draw the horizontal line many times increasing `y` :

```
.model small
.stack 200h

.data
h dw 50
w dw 100
x dw 10
y dw 10
k1 db 15
k2 db 0

.code
start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 0      ; graphics mode
mov al, 13h 
int 10h

; main loop
mov cx, 50
pg:
push cx

; top line
mov cx, x;+w    ; column
add cx, w
mov dx, y      ; row
mov al, k1     ; white
p1:
mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
int 10h
dec cx
cmp cx, x
jae p1

pop cx
inc y         ;<============= NEXT HORIZONTAL LINE WILL BE DRAWN IN THE NEXT LINE.
dec cx
cmp cx, 50
;inc x
;inc y
jna pg

mov ah,00      ; read keyboard
int 16h         

mov ah,00      ; text mode
mov al,03
int 10h

mov ah,4ch     ; exit
int 21h

end start
```

Comment: Not all the constants have to become variables.  As much as possible should remain assemble-time constants.

Comment: This is assembly language.  There's no compiler to optimize away any future-proofing, so it's not a good habit or suggestion to code this way.  An important part of writing good code is figuring out what can be an assemble-time constant.

Comment: I don't like suggesting bad habits or practices in the first place.  If you'd explained the error instead of just giving the fix, this would be a better answer.  I did that briefly in a comment on the question (once I figured out that the OP was trying to modify constants at run-time, not just make them larger and re-assemble!)  The whole answer to the problem hinges on understanding the difference between an assemble-time constant that can be encoded right into the instructions, vs. load/store to mem.  Thinking about which is which for the OPs problem will help understanding, I think.

Comment: Such a simple thing, thank you Jose, however I had to leave k1 and k2 as constants otherwise "operand type do not match" appear. Just wonder why "dd" type didnt work? have you any idea how to bounce it from edges and fill up inside with colour? thank for you all guys